# one button with two functions

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

When I press the button onces, I want to start count, and when I press again to stop count. I know that to work two functions with one button onclick event, it is seperate with ";". Any suggestion? This code works well with two buttons each for one function. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer();stopCount();" />
</form>
```

javascript code:

```
var c=0;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').value=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
{
timer_is_on=1;
timedCount();
}
}

function stopCount()
{
clearTimeout(t);
timer_is_on=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my untested solution with a few tips thrown in for good measure.

First, I think you can probably get rid of the `<form>` and `</form>` tags.

Second, you may find it helpful to give your variables meaningful names, not just `c` or `t`

Third, change timer is on to a boolean: `var timer_is_on = false;`

Fouth change the button to this: `<input type="button" value="Start count!" onclick="doTimer();" />`

Fifth replace your code with this:

```
function doTimer(){

  if( timer_is_on ){

    // Code to start the timer
    // and any other code you want

    timer_is_on = false;

  }else{

    // Code to stop the timer
    // and any other code you want

    timer_is_on = true;

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Adjam. You help me to make the changes!

Comment: also, indent your code in the future, it will make life easier for you

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
onclick="handleClick();"
```

And your JS:

```
function handleClick() {
  if (timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on = false;
    clearTimeout(t);
  } else {
    timer_is_on = true;
    timedCount();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer! I make the changes and now and never stop when i press the button twice. Why? Also the last ")" is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

That will call one immediately after the other, which makes no sense.

Use a single function, check the value of the flag, and perform the appropriate action.